# Fill remaining height with div (with scrollbar and variable height of first div)

Tags: html, css

**I want two divs:**

The first div `.top` has a variable height (`height: auto`), because if you click on a button inside this div, jQuery loads more HTML ito this div. And when jQuery loads more HTML to `.top`, there are more rows to display and the div gets higher.

The second div `.bottom` has to fill the rest of the page/"mother-div". But if there are too many rows, there should appear a scrollbar (`overflow-y: auto`).
And when the button in `.top` has been clicked and `.top` gets higher, the `.bottom`-div should adjusts its height. So the second div is just allowed to fill the rest of the free space (even if the space gets less after a button click)

**Before the button click**
[image]

**After the button click**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="leftcontent">
    <div class="leftcontent_header">
        <button>buttontext</button>
        <div id="jquery" style="display: none;">This content will be shown when when the button has been clicked.<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="leftcontent_content">
        Maintext<br>
        Maintext<br>
        Maintext<br>
        Maintext<br>
        Maintext<br>
        Maintext<br>
        Maintext<br>
        Maintext<br>
        Maintext<br>
        Maintext<br>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**My current css**

```
.leftcontent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 65%;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.leftcontent_header {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.leftcontent_content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The problem with this code is that not all content in the bottom-div is displayed and the scrollbar looks weird too.

Image of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a padding-bottom: X px; on your bottom ( to be sure there is place in, for your content.) (if the not-displayed content is in bottom).